# Can OuterStarts array of Eigen sparse matrix be accessed directly?

Tags: eigen

I know sparse matrix in Eigen is implemented with four arrays: **Values**, **InnerIndices**, **OuterStarts** and **InnerNNZs**. Is there a way that I can obtain these arrays directly. If not, what's the neat method to do that?

One practical way is creating **OuterStarts** array by myself when iterating over the sparse matrix:

```
for(int k=0;k<mat.outerSize();++k)
{
    for(SparseMatrix<double>::InnerIterator it(mat,k);it;++it)
    {
        //add counter here and get index by it.row()
        cout << it.value() << endl;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When in compressed form:

```
m.valuePtr() // non zero value array. Size is the number of non zeros 
m.outerIndexPtr() // array of outer indices. Size is the number of rows/columns
m.innerIndexPtr() // array of inner indices. Size is the number of non zeros
```